# How can I load a text file into MySQL using Perl?

Tags: mysql, perl

Can anyone tell me how to read data from a text file and store it in a MySQL database using Perl?

For example:

```
StudentID Name Dept
1 Chellappa IT
2 Vijay CSE
3 AAA ECE
```

Comment: That's not really how StackOverflow works. You show us your code and we'll help you fix the problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `DBI` module to connect the database. Read input file and split the value and store into an array. Now insert the array values into database.

Here is a way (please note this code is not tested):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use DBI;

my $dsn = "DBI:mysql:host=hostname; database=dbname; port=portname";

# database connection 
my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn,"username","password") or die "Couldn't connect to MySQL server: $!";

my $query = 'INSERT INTO tableName (StudentID,Name,Dept) VALUES (?,?,?)';
my $sth = $dbh->prepare($query) or die "Prepare failed: " . $dbh->errstr();

open my $fh, "<", "file.txt" or die $!;
<$fh>;  #skip header

while (<$fh>)
{
    chomp;
    my @vals = split;
    $sth->execute(@vals);
}
close $fh;
```

Comment: You'll want to skip the header line of the file. Also `split /\s+/, $_` can be simplified to just `split`.

Comment: @DaveCross: Thanks. :) and simplified the split line.

Answer (score 3):

99.9% of the time, the best approach for this kind of thing is to use the native bulk load tools that are specific to the target database. In this case, that would be [`LOAD DATA INFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html) or its command line equivalent, [`mysqlimport`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqlimport.html).

We can use Perl to massage the data into the correct format:

```
$ perl -wlne 'next if $. == 1; s/\s+/\t/g; print;' input.txt > output.txt
```

And then use `mysqlimport` to load it:

```
$ mysqlimport [options] db_name output.txt
```

If your example really is as simple as what you posted, you could actually load your file as-is just by specifying some additional options for `mysqlimport`:

```
$ mysqlimport --ignore-lines=1 --fields-terminated-by=' ' [options ...] db_name input.txt
```